# Import of csv without header results in one Line; Split header from data

Tags: r, csv

i´m new to R and R Studio, but i want to learn. 
As a Result of this

```
GET(
  url = "https://api.binance.com",
  path = "api/v3/ticker/bookTicker",
) -> BinanceRes
content(BinanceRes, as="parsed")
cat(content(BinanceRes, "text"), sep = "\n", file = "BinanceImport2.csv", append = FALSE)
```

i get a csv, which content looks like this in the editor

> [{"symbol":"ETHBTC","bidPrice":"0.01965100","bidQty":"0.30700000","askPrice":"0.01965200","askQty":"1.79400000"},{"symbol":"LTCBTC","bidPrice":"0.00626400","bidQty":"0.52000000","askPrice":"0.00626700","askQty":"10.00000000"},{"symbol":"BNBBTC","bidPrice":"0.00217120","bidQty":"0.18000000","askPrice":"0.00217180","askQty":"4.88000000"},{"symbol":"NEOBTC","bidPrice":"0.00118200","bidQty":"151.84000000","askPrice":"0.00118300","askQty":"385.56000000"},...

How do i re-import that csv in a dataframe which looks like this?

```
symbol   bidPrice     bidQty   ... 
ETHBTC   0.01965100   0.307 
LTCBTC   0.006...
```

All my tries with `read.table` and `read.csv` ended in Tables with only one Line or in strange things like V1 to V25xx. Completely far away from accessing single data. What keywords should i use for internet research? All my results had csv with headers and not this "crap":"whatever" combined thing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to R! This is a simple solution using dplyr (part of the [tidyverse](https://www.tidyverse.org/)):

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
library(httr)

BinanceRes <- GET(
  url = "https://api.binance.com",
  path = "api/v3/ticker/bookTicker",
) 

df <- bind_rows(content(BinanceRes))

head(df)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 5
#>   symbol  bidPrice   bidQty       askPrice   askQty      
#>   <chr>   <chr>      <chr>        <chr>      <chr>       
#> 1 ETHBTC  0.01977000 1.81900000   0.01977300 2.91000000  
#> 2 LTCBTC  0.00626500 30.00000000  0.00627000 31.29000000 
#> 3 BNBBTC  0.00219720 16.72000000  0.00219770 0.58000000  
#> 4 NEOBTC  0.00117800 83.67000000  0.00117900 0.16000000  
#> 5 QTUMETH 0.01174000 1.34000000   0.01177300 200.00000000
#> 6 EOSETH  0.01808500 300.00000000 0.01810700 124.12000000
```

<sup>Created on 2019-11-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: thanks! Working :) I managed to import some more data working with bind_rows(data$ticker). But i got stuck here. How can i extract symbol (between $) out of this:
data$btceth$buy   data$btcada$vol  ...

Comment: Glad to hear! Sorry I don’t follow. I think it qualifies as a new question. Can you post the code you used so far. What is the data variable?